# Is it possible to merge after cherry-pick and rebase?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick, git-merge-conflict

Is it possible to merge at step 4 without conflict?

1. cherry-pick commit 'E' from branch1 to branch2

   ```
    branch1 : A - B - C - D - E
                    \
    branch2 :         F - G - E(cherry-pick from 1)
   ```
2. The commits are added to branch2

   ```
    branch1 : A - B - C - D - E
                   \
    branch2 :         F - G - E - H - I
   ```
3. Rebase interactively and squash commits because they are the solution to the same problem.

   (Now, I think it was bad decision...)

   ```
    branch1 : A - B - C - D - E
                   \
    branch2 :        F - G - I'
   ```
4. Cherry-pick squashed commit again to branch1...

   (Would it be better to cherry-pick commit H, I to branch1?)

   ```
    branch1 : A - B - C - D - E - I'(conflict?)
                    \
    branch2 :         F - G - I'
   ```

Comment: Your diagram in step 4 looks like a cherry-pick, not a merge.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question, but nobody will be able to provide a definitive answer unless you were to provide the actual git repository so the changesets could be examined.

The fact that there is a merge conflict has nothing to do with whether commits H and I are cherry picked individually or are rebased together. The fact that E got squashed as well *might* be a factor.

More importantly, though, is a small problem with the premise of the question. "Is it possible to merge **without conflict**?" Why does this merge need to happen without conflict? It's probably correct and appropriate for there to be a conflict.

When git says "there's a conflict", that does NOT mean "you messed up, these can't be merged." Rather, it means "I (git) can't figure out how these changes should be merged. I need human help."

**Here's the solution**:
Get some good diff/merge software (I use P4Merge on Windows, but there are lots of options). Examine the contents of each of the commits in question. Understand what the conflict is (most likely H or I changed a line that had been changed in E, or maybe H and I depend on changes that had already been made in F or G). Resolve each conflict: this may mean keeping the original line, or keeping the newer line, or modifying the line in a new way that incorporates changes from both branches - it's entirely context dependent.

Don't be afraid to consult with team members on conflict resolution - chances are you'll be deciding if some of their work is going to get erased.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
As you said, if there is a conflict, i'll try to resolve it.
However, i thought if i didn't squashed the commits, it's likely that no conflict has occured.
But on the other hand , i thought small commits for the same goal make the branch difficult to manage unnecessarily.

Comment: I think the "best practice" for git is usually to tend towards frequent, small commits. If there is a conflict caused by the squashing, it is that you included E in the squash, then tried to cherry-pick it back.